# Receiving 408 request timeout when we try to put an object to a Forge bucket

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

We are trying to upload a 'bigger' model to a forge bucket via the model derivative API.
This model has a file size of 956MB and the extension .nwd

```
const uploadPromise = http(uploadUrl(socketId), {
    method: 'PUT',
    data: Body,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${Forge.urns[socketId].autoDeskToken}`,
    },
    maxContentLength: 1024 * 1024 * 1024,
    timeout: 600000,
})

{ Error: Request failed with status code 408
  at createError (/nodejs/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
  at settle (/nodejs/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
  at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/nodejs/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:202:11)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
  at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

The url seems to be correct:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/-BUCKETNAME-/objects/-filename-.nwd

What could be the reason of this error?

This is a problem a customer is experiencing.

kind regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's interesting, the error code 408 is not listed in the documentation of the endpoint: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT. The error code is most likely coming from some middle-layer (Apigee), and not from the Forge servers directly.

However, to upload a file this big, I'd strongly suggest using the "resumable upload" feature that's available in the Data Management service. You can find an example of how the resumable upload works in my TypeScript code here: https://github.com/petrbroz/vscode-forge-tools/blob/develop/src/commands/data-management.ts#L230-L272.

Comment: Let me also pass this information to the Data Management service team, to see where the 408 could be coming from.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to receive more info about that.